# How can I create a csv from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very unique situation here. My dictionary has string keys and `pandas.DataFrame` values:

```
d = {'0':df1,'1':df2,'2':df3,...,'1000':df1001}
```

I want to create a seperate csv file for df1, df2, df3 and so on up to df1001 with the file names as '0'.csv,'1'.csv,'2'.csv and so on upto '1000'.csv respectively.

I have tried using the pandas to_csv but that does not help the cause. Can anyone please help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors using `to_csv()` ?

Answer (score 5):

Calling `to_csv` should definitely work.

```
for k, v in d.items():
    v.to_csv("{0}.csv".format(k))
```

Comment: Or with Python 3.6+: `f'{k}.csv'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I wonder why it did not work when I tried it. But then again. Thanks a lot. you probably saved my life.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommand using the pandas library. The pandas library can easily create a dataframe from a dict. This dataframe can be stored as a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
```

Now you can save the pandas dataframe as a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv('results.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: This does not satisfy OP's problem. OP wants `n` CSVs for `n` entries in the dict.